# What would happen to electricity if earth's magnetic field reversed?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, geomagnetism

In particular, what would happen to our communication system? Is there a way to recreate it? Is there any intrinsic difference and difficulty within the process? I mean: can you simply 'reverse' everything in some ways, or is the process more complicated than that?

**Edit**: I'm sorry if you didn't understand my question. I was just curious because I've read a terribile book in which this exact thing happens, and it is said that 'there is a way to recreate electric energy'. I was just asking if you actually need to invent a new way to recreate electric energy, if actually the magnetic field of earth would affect our communication system and how. I just wanted the basic idea, I wasn't looking for detailed and complicated answers. I tried to googled it but I didn't find answers to that topic and I thought about this website - if you find out some good references about this, please let me know. Looking at your responses, probably this isn't the good place to ask for this question, probably because it isn't detailed enough... let me know it and I'll cancel the question, eventually if you won't cancel it for me.

Comment: -1 No research effort. Have you tried googling your title?

Comment: Your question seems to be very broad :  effects on communications systems, how to (re)create it, difficulties in the process, effect on Maxwell's equations. What exactly is your difficulty? As for the effect on Maxwell's equations,  do you think they change when you turn a bar magnet upside down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes in the magnetic field can induce voltages and currents in (large scale) power and communication line circuits according to the Maxwell-Faraday equation $$\int_{\partial S} \vec E d\vec r=-\frac {d}{dt}\int_S \vec B d\vec S \tag 1$$ This shows that the induced voltages depends on the lateral extension of the considered circuit and on the speed of change of the magnetic field. Significant detrimental effects can occur in magnetic storms on earth produced by solar flares emitting protons and thus producing fluctuating currents and magnetic fields near earth. Changes of earth's magnetic field caused by changing currents in the inner core are usually extremely slow and on the time scale of years to millions of years. They are called secular variations. Even if the earth's magnetic field with a typical strength of 45 $\mu T$ would reverse on that time scale this would not produce any noticeable induced voltages and thus disturbances in our power lines. In [major magnetic storms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_storm_of_1859) magnetic field changes larger than 0.25 $\mu T$ can happen on a scale of minutes . Such [magnetic storms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm) can cause major disruptions in power and communication lines.